# NextJS - Global style in _app.js is not being applied

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I just created a new project and followed this page from NextJS documentation:
https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/built-in-css-support

I copied every step under "Adding a Global Stylesheet" but the global styles are not being applied. Here is what I have currently:

_app.js file:

```
import "../global.css";

export default function App({ Component, pageProps }) {
  return <Component {...pageProps} />;
}
```

global.css file:

```
body {
  font-family: "SF Pro Text", "SF Pro Icons", "Helvetica Neue", "Helvetica",
    "Arial", sans-serif;
  padding: 20px 20px 60px;
  max-width: 680px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: red;
}
```

index.js file:

```
export default function Home() {
  return (
    <div>
      <p>Hello World!</p>
    </div>
  );
}
```

My project folder structure:
[image: Project folder structure]

And here is the page I get after running 'npm run dev':[image: Loaded index page with no global styles applied]

You can see that the page has none of the global styles and the body element's styles are also empty.

Comment: can you also post a image of your folder structure?

Comment: change your path to `../utils/global.css`

Comment: @KunalTanwar The file is not under utils. I edited the picture again without any folder except for pages.

Comment: then use `./global.css`

Comment: It is not under pages either so ./global.css wouldn't work, but I tried it anyways and it didn't work.

Comment: your `global.css` file located in the source folder! right? Also, did you try restarting the server?

Comment: Yes it is under the src but not in pages, so I need ../global.css to access it since using ./ in _app.js refers to files within /pages like index.js and accessing files in src needs ../.
I also tried restarting the server multiple times.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried deleting the .next folder and restarting the server and it finally worked. I think the issue is that creating /pages/_app.js requires you to recreate the whole build and just restarting it without deleting .next entirely isn't enough.

Comment: This did not work for me unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes browsers do cache style files. You can force browser to download new style file by refreshing page with Ctrl + F5.